# Proving or Disproving Logical Equivalence Involving Inverse Quantifiers

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

Let $P$ be the statement: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y \geq x \,\, \wedge \,\, |f(y)| \geq 1$

Let $Q$ be the statement: $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y \geq x \Rightarrow \, |f(y)| \geq 1$.

Prove, or disprove by counterexample, that (a) $P \Rightarrow Q$ and (b) $Q \Rightarrow P$.

So I've noted that the inverse of the statement $Q$ can be represented as:
$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y \geq x \,\, \wedge \,\, |f(y)| < 1$, which gets me to a form closer to $P$, but I'm not sure how to complete the proofs required from there. Is that even the right direction to try?

Comment: You'll need to use some information abut the $\leq$ relation on $\mathbb R$, specifically that every two elements are comparable (or at least that, for every two elements $u,v$, there is some $w$ that is $\geq$ both). In other words, this is not a matter of pure logic.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Hmmmm I'm not sure how to incorporate that into a functional definition for f(y). Would you be able to be a little bit more specific?

Comment: I didn't say anything about incorporating a property of $\leq$ into a definition for $f(y)$. I don't see anything in my comment or in the question to suggest that $f$ should be definable at all. To be more specific about my comment: One of the implications (a), (b) in the question is true in $\mathbb R$ but not in some other structures where $\leq$ is interpreted differently.